# Inserting an item into a list before all items starting with a phrase and whose next line starts with a different phrase

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have something like the list:

```
["Monkey: 1", "Banana Cake: First Time", "Random Line: {Stuff}", "Monkey: 2", "Orange Juice", "Monkey: 3", "Banana Cake: Again"]
```

I'd like to know how to insert a list element, say `"Good Monkey"`, after all elements starting with `"Monkey"` such that the next item in the list starts with `"Banana"`, in a way that generalizes to huge lists.

In other words, if I have a list, I want to be able to insert an item after every item beginning with a certain phrase whose proceeding item begins with another given phrase.

A sample output would be:

["Monkey: 1", "Good Monkey", "Banana Cake: First Time", "Random Line: {Stuff}", "Monkey: 2", "Orange Juice", "Monkey: 3", "Good Monkey", "Banana Cake: Again"]

Comment: Could you provide some sample output to demonstrate what you mean?  The way I read this is as placing the new item between all `Monkey...` and `Banana...` elements

Comment: I edited the post to include one example too add the phrase "Good Monkey" after all items starting with "Monkey" whose proceeding items start with "Banana."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [`pairwise` itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
from itertools import tee    

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

l = ["Monkey: 1", "Banana Cake: First Time", "Random Line: {Stuff}", "Monkey: 2", "Orange Juice", "Monkey: 3", "Banana Cake: Again"]

l = [x for a, b in pairwise(l) for x in ((a, 'Good Monkey') if a.startswith('Monkey') and b.startswith('Banana') else (a,))] + [l[-1]]
```

This works, and is O(n), but I'm not thrilled with the kludgy `+ [l[-1]]` at the end of the last line

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution:

```
def insert_between(lst, preceding_prefix, following_prefix, item):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst) - 1:
        if lst[i].startswith(preceding_prefix) and lst[i+1].startswith(following_prefix):
            lst.insert(i+1, item)
            i += 2  # Advance twice to skip over the item we just inserted
        else:
            i += 1

lst = ["Monkey: 1", "Banana Cake: First Time", "Random Line: {Stuff}", "Monkey: 2", "Orange Juice", "Monkey: 3", "Banana Cake: Again"]
insert_between(lst, "Monkey", "Banana", "Good Monkey")
print(lst)

# Output;
# ['Monkey: 1', 'Good Monkey', 'Banana Cake: First Time', 'Random Line: {Stuff}', 'Monkey: 2', 'Orange Juice', 'Monkey: 3', 'Good Monkey', 'Banana Cake: Again']
```